# Program won't run successfully? Segmentation fault 11, expression treated as a null pointer; C

Tags: c

I get a segmentation fault when I run my program, and these errors when I compile it. What must i do to get my program working.

```
./documents/TEST/TEST/main.c:117:72: warning: expression which evaluates to zero
          treated as a null pointer constant of type 'const char *'
          [-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]
                strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].name, '\0');
                                                                           ^~~~
    /usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:33: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
      __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
                                    ^
    ./documents/TEST/TEST/main.c:121:73: warning: expression which evaluates to zero
          treated as a null pointer constant of type 'const char *'
          [-Wnon-literal-null-conversion]
                strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].color, '\0');
                                                                            ^~~~
    /usr/include/secure/_string.h:83:33: note: expanded from macro 'strcpy'
      __builtin___strcpy_chk (dest, src, __darwin_obsz (dest))
```

Comment: Would be nice to know which lines the messages refer to.

Comment: Well it lists the lines the it is referring to in the error code, which are:             `strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].name, '\0');` and             `strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].color, '\0');`

Comment: '\0' is not a string, but "" is a zero-length NULL terminated string, so swap to that!

Comment: "What must I do to get my program working?" - good ole debuggin', maybe? :) Be it by `printf`, or by `gdb`, it can drastically help in improving code quality!

Comment: I am, and I have fixed some other things such as values that should have been initialized to 0, but i do not know what this segmentation fault is, and so it is somewhat difficult to try to fix it. Which is why help from someone with more knowledge would be benifitial.

Comment: start using printf to see in which step did your program break. If message from printf appears, then it means, your program run after this step. Do many printf and you will have more information on what's going on. We won't do this for you.

Comment: Remember, when `printf`'ing, terminate your lines with a `\n` (newline). This will cause the line to be flushed, so will appear on the console. If you omit this, the line may never get to the console even though the `printf` is before the segfaulting code.

Comment: So you'd like help with a program that seg faults, but don't think it necessary to show the code.  Good luck with that.

Comment: @ScottHunter: It was there some minutes ago. He maybe should put it back.

Comment: this line, assuming 'name' is an array and not just a pointer to char: strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].name, '\0'); should be: dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].name[0] = '\0'; if just a pointer to char, then it should be: dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].name = NULL;

Comment: this line, assuming 'color' is an array and not just a pointer to char: strcpy(dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].color, '\0'); should be: dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].color[0] = '\0';  If just a pointer to char, then it should be: dragon_index->team[dragon_index->num_dragons].color = NULL;

Comment: I would hope that your C instructor has told you that warnings are problems in the code the should/MUST be fixed.  Why are you trying to execute something that does not successfully compile?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing '\0', which is of type char, and has the value 0 to strcpy, which would expect an argument of type const char* as second arguments. Recall that '\0' and "\0" are NOT the same.

Comment: I fixed that error, and get no other "error" codes, and it compiles unlike before. But it doesn't run

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` expects a *string* to copy, which is represented by a *pointer* to its first character; `'\0'` is a single character.  I'm guessing you mean to use `""` instead.

Comment: It seems that all of my errors are gone after fixing that, but my code still won't run. It still says set fault 11

Comment: maybe start checking for errors on fopen and fscanf? And really, saying it still won't run doesn't give enough information on how to help you.